distutils.msvccompiler module is missing during spleeter installation
I am trying to install Spleeter on my Windows 11 Home 64-bit PC with Python 3.12.0, NumPy 2.1.2 and FFmpeg 2024-12-16 for the first time and I get the following message on my command prompt terminal when I run pip install spleeter. Any solutions or workarounds for this problem and any suggestions to improve this question are much appreciated.
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))': /simple/spleeter/
Collecting spleeter
  Using cached spleeter-2.1.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (10 kB)
Collecting ffmpeg-python==0.2.0 (from spleeter)
  Using cached ffmpeg_python-0.2.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.7 kB)
Collecting httpx<0.17.0,>=0.16.1 (from httpx[http2]<0.17.0,>=0.16.1->spleeter)
  Using cached httpx-0.16.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (38 kB)
Collecting librosa==0.8.0 (from spleeter)
  Using cached librosa-0.8.0.tar.gz (183 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Collecting norbert==0.2.1 (from spleeter)
  Using cached norbert-0.2.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.8 kB)
Collecting numpy<1.19.0,>=1.16.0 (from spleeter)
  Using cached numpy-1.18.5.zip (5.4 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [26 lines of output]
      Running from numpy source directory.
      <string>:461: UserWarning: Unrecognized setuptools command, proceeding with generating Cython sources and expanding templates
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 149, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
          return hook(metadata_directory, config_settings)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-jh79_vav\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 377, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
          self.run_setup()
        File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-jh79_vav\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 522, in run_setup
          super().run_setup(setup_script=setup_script)
        File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-jh79_vav\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 320, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 488, in <module>
        File "<string>", line 465, in setup_package
        File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-wz5wh6ix\numpy_c70a3ebc725446b397c2c2fb270c9aff\numpy\distutils\core.py", line 26, in <module>
          from numpy.distutils.command import config, config_compiler, \
        File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-wz5wh6ix\numpy_c70a3ebc725446b397c2c2fb270c9aff\numpy\distutils\command\config.py", line 20, in <module>
          from numpy.distutils.mingw32ccompiler import generate_manifest
        File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-wz5wh6ix\numpy_c70a3ebc725446b397c2c2fb270c9aff\numpy\distutils\mingw32ccompiler.py", line 34, in <module>
          from distutils.msvccompiler import get_build_version as get_build_msvc_version
      ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils.msvccompiler'
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.

I tried installing the Spleeter library using pip install spleeter on my Windows 11 PC with Python 3.12, NumPy 2.1.2, and FFmpeg 2024-12-16. But during the installation process, I faced an error related to the missing distutils.msvccompiler module. The installation fails at the step where it tries to build numpy and other dependencies, throwing the error message about the missing module.
I expected the Spleeter package to install without errors and for me to be able to use it for audio separation tasks.

It is explicitly stated on PyPI that the stable release of spleeter i.e. v2.4.0 requires: Python >=3.7.1, <3.11. You are using an unsupported version i.e. Python 3.12.
You'd have to downgrade your python to any of the supported versions i.e. Python 3.7-3.10 in order to use this library. I'd suggest you use Python 3.10.
